# Perl Crypt:CBC encrypts/decrypts only first list

Tags: perl, crypt, cbc-mode

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Crypt::CBC;

my $scriptkey = qx(cat /tmp/scriptkeyfile);
chomp $scriptkey;

print new Crypt::CBC(-key=>"$scriptkey",-salt=>"my_salt")->encrypt(qx(cat $ARGV[0]));
```

This script only encrypts first line of given file. If I change encrypt to decrypt, it will only decrypt one line of given file. How to change this, to crypt whole file.

Comment: Using `cat` and a system call to read a file is not the best of options to get the file's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qx` is list context returns a list of lines, so

```
->encrypt(qx( ... ))
```

results in

```
->encrypt($line1, $line2, $line3, ...)
```

but

```
->encrypt($plaintext)
```

is expected. Use `qx` in scalar context to return the entire output as one scalar.

```
my $file = qx( prog ... );
die("Can't execute prog: $!\n") if $? == -1;
die("prog killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("prog exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $? >> 8;

my $cypher = Crypt::CBC->new( ... );
print $cypher->encrypt($file);
```

I'm assuming you aren't actually using `cat`, that it's just an example.

Comment: Thank you. It was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

The [Crypt::CBC docs actually explain](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::CBC#finish) how to encrypt a whole file.

> The CBC algorithm must buffer data blocks internally until they are even multiples of the encryption algorithm's blocksize (typically 8 bytes). After the last call to crypt() you should call finish(). This flushes the internal buffer and returns any leftover ciphertext.
>
> In a typical application you will read the plaintext from a file or input stream and write the result to standard output in a loop that might look like this:
>
> ```
>    $cipher = new Crypt::CBC('hey jude!');
>    $cipher->start('encrypting');
>    print $cipher->crypt($_) while <>;
>    print $cipher->finish();
> ```

So your program might look like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::CBC;
use File::Slurp;

my $scriptkey = read_file( '/tmp/scriptkeyfile' );
chomp $scriptkey;

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!; # sanitize this!!!

my $encrypted;
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key => $scriptkey, -salt => "my_salt" );
$cipher->start('encrypting');
$encrypted .= $cipher->crypt($_) while <$fh>;
$encrypted .= $cipher->finish;

close $fh;
```

Comment: @Borodin Meh. I clicked the wrong button for the quote. Thanks. I overwrote it, though :P